# Custom form validation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, client-side-validation

Im using jQuery to make a custom form validation.

My issue is that when its alerting an error, i get every error in a separate alert dialog.. my goal is to have it list all errors in 1 single alert.

How do i achieve that?

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("form.kontakt-form").on("submit", function(e){
    jQuery(".kontakt-form input").each(function(){

      var name = jQuery(this).attr("placeholder");

      if(jQuery(this).val() == ""){
        alert("There was an error" + " " + name);
        e.preventDefault();
      }else{
        return true; 
      }
    });
  });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var nameErr = '';
      jQuery("form.kontakt-form").on("submit", function(e){
        jQuery(".kontakt-form input").each(function(){

          var name = jQuery(this).attr("placeholder");

          if(jQuery(this).val() == ""){
           nameErr += '\n'+name;
            e.preventDefault();
          }else{
            return true; 
          }
        });
        alert("There was an error" + " " + nameErr);
      });    
    })
```

Comment: Im experiencing some issues with the validation. If a user has tried to submit the form with an error, the error will reappear even if fixed and resubmitted. Also if submitted correct first time, the alert will still appear but with no errors in it (obviously).. here is a link to the development site http://ddjs.simplemedia.dk/kontakt

Comment: Pls post new question as its different issue than your This question. I will answer there. Just put Link of your new question in Comment .